# Unit tests - run task programmatically

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm creating custom task for gradle. I don't know how I can create task which will use my custom task class. Is it possible? I want to create this task for functional tests which will be runned on jenkins.

This is my custom task:

```
package pl.gradle

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    public MyCustomTask() {
        // do something
    }

    @TaskAction
    def build() {
        ant.echo(message: "only for tests")
    }               
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
package pl.gradle

import static org.junit.Assert.*

import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test

class MyCustomTaskTest {

    private Project project;
    def task

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        task = project.task("build", type: MyCustomTask)
    }

    @Test
    public void taskCreatedProperly() {
        assertTrue(task instanceof MyCustomTask)
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRunTask() {
//      task.execute() // how to run this task? I want to run build() method from MyCustomTask class which is @TaskAction
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProjectBuilder` is meant for lower-level tests that don't execute tasks. Its sweet spot is testing *plugins*. In addition you'd write higher-level tests that execute real builds (and therefore also tasks). You'd typically use the Gradle tooling API to kick off these builds. Check out the tooling API samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I wanted. I'll try to use it.

Comment: @pepuch Can you post an answer with the code you came up with?

Answer (score 0):

Call [Action.execute](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Action.html#execute-T-) yourself for each of the task actions:

```
project.tasks.getByName("myTask").with { Task task ->
    assertEquals task.group, 'My Group'

    task.actions.each { Action action ->
        action.execute task
    }
}
```

I've previously mentioned this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63613564/410939