# How to run test "running task" in unit test

Tags: groovy, gradle

For instance, following is gradle doc:

```
class GreetingTaskTest {
    @Test
    public void canAddTaskToProject() {
        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        def task = project.task('greeting', type: GreetingTask)
        assertTrue(task instanceof GreetingTask)
    }
}
```

I hope test following

```
class GreetingTaskTest {
    @Test
    public void canAddTaskToProject() {
        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        def task = project.task('greeting', type: GreetingTask) {
            methInGreetingTask()
        }
        task.run()
    }
}
```

My question is: how to do it?

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit tests - run task programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557786/unit-tests-run-task-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

The thing with gradle tasks is that it's rather their actions that get executed. You can get those via `.actions` for a task and then execute each of those with `.execute(task)`.

```
project.tasks.getByName("myTask").with { Task task ->
    assertEquals task.group, 'My Group'

    task.actions.each { Action action ->
        action.execute task
    }
}
```

Tested with gradle 6.4 / groovy 2.5.10

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're a looking for `execute` method defined in `AbstractTask` - gradle internales. See the [docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html).

Comment: @zhadoxietu does it answer your question?